# Migration from license apk to in-app purchases - how to migrate existing licence owners?

Tags: google-play, android-inapp-purchase

I plan to migrate from licence apk model, where free app checks if separate paid blank licence apk is present, to in-app purchases (google play billing 3+).

How do I "migrate" the existing users (< 500) that bought the licence apk? The app does not have any back-end. I want to retire the licence apk over time.

My first idea was to create a free product for which I can offer a link to users with licence files. However, one cannot create a free in-app purchase. So I was thinking of somehow combining both approaches.

Any good ideas or viable alternative approaches appreciated. I haven't found any good recent information regarding this.

Comment: You cannot offer a free product, but can create a product and then offer promo codes for users to get it free.

Comment: I know that. Promo links are one-time only, so I need to somehow provide a different code to each user that has the licence file installed. Ideally the code would also work just for that user & I don't know how to realize that in an app without any back-end.

Comment: @JureSencar have you solved this issue? I am facing similar problem

Comment: Not really. I am running both options side-by-side for years now. App offers users in-app purchase only, but it's backwards compatible with licence file. At some point I will just retire the licence file. That app did not have a large user base, so I did not invest into some sort of promo code delivery. Maybe a banner with "write email for promo code" that shows if user has licence file and no in-app purchase would be a way to go.